# How to change the text color of a cell text in a HTML.GRID MVC C#

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a model that comes in that might have a property of `ValidEmployeeId`.

If `ValidEmployeeId = false`, then I want to change the respective records cell text to red.

How can i do that **without** using JavaScript to loop through each row / cell?

How can I change the color of a cell's text?

Let me elaborate even more to avoid confusion. I want the row to have the **Employee ID's** cell text as red if this property is false. Of course the text of the other cells will not change.

NOTE: I do **not** want to use Jquery / Javscript to loop through the grid and dynamically add  a "text-danger" class to each cell . There has to be a way to do it in HTML.GRID C# right?

```
@model List<EmployeeModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employees";
}

@using GridMvc.Html;

<h3>@ViewBag.Title</h3>

<hr/>

<div class="grid grid-border">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Named("employeeGrid").Columns(columns =>
    {


        columns.Add(q => q.EmployeeId).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(150).Titled("ID");
        columns.Add(q => q.EmployeeRole).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(150).Titled("Role");
        columns.Add(q => q.EmployeeStatus).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(150).Titled("Status");
        columns.Add(q => q.EmployeeName).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(150).Titled("Namen");
    }).WithPaging(100)
</div>
```

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/